# Google analytics demo account

Tags: seo, google-analytics, web-analytics

I am keen on learning more about Google Analytics but the accounts I have access to only have 70% of the functionalities implemented.

Is there a google demo/test account (free service) that I could use to explore all GA Features?

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any official Analytics demo account.
But Google Analytics is free, so create an account and play with it or/and learn with the tutorials !

[Google Analytics IQ Lessons](http://www.google.com/intl/en/analytics/iq.html)
[Google Analytics Product Tour](http://www.google.com/analytics/features/tour.html)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but a new account is not populated with data so I am not able to build any reports. I have access to 2 accounts already but not all features are available today.